# Docker: How does Nginx forward requests to a container without the VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, docker, nginx

In almost every Nginx related webpage I've visited, it says that if a docker container is to be reachable from the Nginx reverse proxy, then it requires the VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable.

However, I've found out that this doesn't seem to be the case. For instance, in [this](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/master/docker-compose.override.yml) docker-compose file, there's only 1 service with the VIRTUAL_HOST specified and that is the "web" service. And when I tested the system that uses this docker-compose file and checked Wireshark, I noticed that Nginx manages to communicate with the "jobs" service, despite it not having the VIRTUAL_HOST variable. How is this possible?

Comment: Can you link to a website that claims this? You have to configure a "virtual host" in Nginx (there is no such terminology in Nginx, do you mean "server block"?), but then you can decide to which Docker-exposed port you want to proxy requests.

Comment: @slhck Here's one: https://medium.com/@francoisromain/host-multiple-websites-with-https-inside-docker-containers-on-a-single-server-18467484ab95

Comment: Here's another one: https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/host-multiple-websites-docker-nginx/

Comment: I don't see an Nginx Docker Compose service being used in that project. Which Nginx did you use then?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no concept of "virtual hosts" in Nginx. These are called "server" blocks, as you can specify different servers listening on different hostnames. The `VIRTURAL_HOST` environment variable is a Docker-specific concept—actually, it's only part of the [`nginx-proxy` Docker service](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy).

When using Nginx *outside* a Docker environment, you'd configure it to listen to a particular hostname, then forward the requests coming in to the port that is exposed by a running Docker container. For example, your server block could look like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name <DOMAIN>; # Replace this with your site's domain.

  root /var/www/<DOMAIN>;

  try_files $uri @docker;

  location @docker {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

Here, Nginx running on your system would forward requests to a Docker container that exposes port 3000. Depending on how you set this up, you can of course proxy to multiple containers at the same time.

The other variant is running Nginx *inside* a Docker environment, typically within Docker Compose, such that Nginx knows about the presence of other Docker containers, which it infers from the `VIRTUAL_HOST` variable. As mentioned in the second link you added:

> The proxy looks for containers with the `VIRTUAL_HOST` variable enabled. (…) The proxy will see that person A has requested blog.example.com and will route (or proxy!) their request to the correct container.

That means, instead of explicitly specifying an IP address and port (like 3000 above), you you can instead directly link the `nginx-proxy` container to the application container. For more, read [this README](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy).

Comment: Right, but in the first link that I added, you can see that one of the services has an environment variable called 'RAILS_ENV'. When I tested the docker network with Wireshark, I noticed that Nginx forwards requests to the service with this variable. Would this environment variable have to be specified in server blocks as well?

Comment: I don't see an nginx service in your first link? `RAILS_ENV` is Rails-specific and is not used by Nginx.